# How to change Optional field(Java 8 API) into Java 7

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have an application taken from Github in which Java 8 API, namely Optional keyword, is used. But the environment which I would like to run this app is setup to JDK_7. Hence, as I have zero experience with Java 8 API, Can anybody give an alternative code block of the following sample code:

```
public final static Optional<String> reverseGeocodeFromLatLong(final double latitude, final double longitude) {
    final StringBuilder bingMapsURL = new StringBuilder();
    bingMapsURL
            .append(BING_MAPS_URL_START)
            .append(latitude)
            .append(",")
            .append(longitude)
            .append(BING_MAPS_URL_MIDDLE_JSON)
            .append(Constants.BING_MAPS_API_KEY_VALUE);
    LOGGER.debug("BingMapsURL==>{}", bingMapsURL.toString());

    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        final URL url = new URL(bingMapsURL.toString());
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()){
            inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            return getStateFromJSONResponse(inputStream);
        }
    } catch (final Throwable throwable) {
        LOGGER.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(null != inputStream) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (final IOException ioException) {
                LOGGER.error(ioException.getMessage(), ioException);
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        httpURLConnection = null;
    }
    return Optional.absent();
}
```

Comment: Code compiled for Java 8, or that uses classes that are only available in the Java 8 standard library such as `Optional`, are not going to work on Java 7. You'll have to use Java 8 to use those.

Comment: I also have zero experience with Java 8, but I can you that `Optional` isn't a keyword, it's a class.  You're going to either have to include a JAR, or refactor this method.

Comment: The optional in that code is not Java 8 API, but fom Guava http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html . Java 8 does not have `Optional.absent()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of Optional is pretty much to force you to not forget null checks, so you could replace `return Optional.absent()` with `return null` and make `getStateFromJSONResponse` return a `String` instead of and `Optional<String>`. Then don't forget to check for `null`s in your code, as now you won't be forced to make the checks.

Comment: If including `Guava` in your project is an option, then that is probably a better approach.